# Small files vs large files for external table performance

Tags: greenplum, external-tables

I'm actually using Greenplum external tables recently, and I'm curious about that:

Is there any performance difference to distribute data of an external table into plenty of small files (less than 100KB) instead of a few large files (maybe tens to hundreds MB)?

Is there any difference besides performance aspect?

Answer (score 0):

For reading: if you have smaller files, you can use multiple gpfdist reader to read files in parallel, possibly from multiple filesystems or I/O channels on the ETL host.
For writing: you need to create multiple external tables, one for each filename. That will blow your catalog up.